# Azure Mobile Services authentication client flow hook

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services

I'm using .NET backend on Azure Mobile Service. It's easy to set up authentication with social identity provider, so that the client can use e.g. Facebook iOS SDK to login, as illustrated in [the official tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-users/)

In custom authentication, as I need to maintain my own Account table according to [the official tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/), I have full control over the registration & login.

I'd like to have a centralized User table to store information about all users, no matter which channel they used to authenticate.

My question is, is there a way for the .NET backend to be notified when a user register or login with a Facebook token? So that a new row can be added to the centralized User table even when the user is using Facebook to authenticate?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the User.GetIdentities() method contains the token and mechanism that was used to authenticate the user.  You can use this to update your table.  For an overview of how to use this token, see this blog post by the team: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, in the sample, there is still a secret handshake; the client has to call InvokeApiAsync on the UserInfoController. Is there a way to make the .NET backend react to the client calling MobileService.LoginAsync(provider) ?
Thank you

Comment: No, there isn't.  The IdP is a separate entity to your backend application and you are just leveraging the token.  As a result, your code does not see the token until their first request.  Until your client makes an API call with the token, your code won't see them.